# Why is a C# console processing multiline paste as Enter key presses?

Tags: c#, console, newline

I have a C# application which handles key presses and will break the loop when the `Enter` key is pressed.  The problem I am encountering is that when a multiline paste event occurs, the console is interpreting the newlines as Enter key presses.

Example that doesn't cause `Enter` keypress:

```
select something \n from somewhere \n where condition
```

Example that does cause `Enter` keypress:

```
select something
from somewhere
where condition
```

Does anyone know why this would be?  And is there any way to stop this without digging into the `WndProc` stuff for intercepting a Paste event?

Comment: Enter key press do \r\n ,which is done in the second example so it explain it as Enter key press

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Enter` key press can't be resolved back into `\r\n` as far as I can tell, so I don't think we can process based on those characters - but I was able to get a hint (for my situation anyway) if the user was pasting multiline text by interrogating `Console.KeyAvailable`.

So now, I look to see if `(Key == ConsoleKey.Enter && Console.KeyAvailable == false)` to determine whether to process it as "genuine" Enter key press or not (as there usually aren't keys available in my situation when Enter is pressed).

See [this commit](https://github.com/sorrell/InteractivePrompt/commit/a8f4ebf7f9dfac08cef7fac02c960c2a81ddeaab) for more info

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, new lines are \r\n. When you press the Enter key, these two characters are input. So if you put a \r before each of your \n they should be treated as newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it looks like someone used Console.ReadLine() to trigger loop break.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx

Effectively loop breaks when you start new line not only press enter Key.